# How to test controller method that use TempData in ASP MVC CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, mstest

I want to write test for my controller method but I have `Nullpointexceprion` for `TempData["EditMember"] = false;` that I using in my method.

I have read several similar threads but I have not found a solution to this problem. I tried to use mocking but I also failed because none of the examples wanted to compile.

Here is my controller method

```cs
    public class MemberController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public MemberController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork as UnitOfWork;
        }


        public IActionResult CreateUpdate(string id = null, string table = null)
        {

            MemberViewModel model = null;

            TempData["EditMember"] = false;
            if (id != null)
            {
                TempData["EditMember"] = true;
                var member = _unitOfWork.MemberRepositories.FindBySRU(id);
                model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Member, MemberViewModel>(member);
            }


            if (model == null)
                model = new MemberViewModel();

            TempData["HealthIssues"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.Player);
            TempData["Guardians"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.Player.Junior);

            return View(model);
        }
```

Test method

```cs
        [TestMethod]
        public void test()
        {
            //Arrange

            var memberController = new MemberController(new UnitOfWork(new DatabaseModel()));


            //Act
            var viewResult = memberController.CreateUpdate() as ViewResult;

            //Assert
        }
```

Is there an easy way to start such a test in ASP CORE using `TempData`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create an `ITempDataDictionary` object first, and then assign it to TempData property on your controller before accessing it. You can easily do it with mocks. Here is an (simplified) example with Moq:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;
using TestProjectMvc.Controllers;

namespace TestProjectMvc.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MemberControllerTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void CreateUpdateTest()
        {
            ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider = Mock.Of<ITempDataProvider>();
            TempDataDictionaryFactory tempDataDictionaryFactory = new TempDataDictionaryFactory(tempDataProvider);
            ITempDataDictionary tempData = tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(new DefaultHttpContext());

            MemberController controller = new MemberController(new UnitOfWork())
            {
                TempData = tempData
            };

            ViewResult viewResult = controller.CreateUpdate(null) as ViewResult;

            Assert.IsFalse((bool)viewResult.TempData["EditMember"]);

            viewResult = controller.CreateUpdate("123") as ViewResult;

            Assert.IsTrue((bool)viewResult.TempData["EditMember"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, now I see. I seen similar solution but did not work because I used wrong library that shows `TempDataDictionary` has 0 arguments. Thanks @Peska I sloved it :)